# Track Custom Policy Signups/-ins to AD B2C with PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, azure-ad-b2c

We recently migrated all our AD B2C apps to use our new Identity Experience Framework (IEF) policies. Since we now want to start also providing business with some base analytics we connected PowerBI to our Azure AD B2C tenant. 
The problem here is, that we cannot track signins or signups on a per app basis since all gets tracked under the app "ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework".

Is there a way to track signins and signups on a per app basis even though we are using IEF?

Answer (score 0):

You can [collect the sign-up and sign-in events in Azure Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-guide-eventlogger-appins) and then [feed these events to Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/export-power-bi).

To collect the application identifier for a sign-up or sign-in event, you must:

1. Declare a claim type for the application identifier.

```xml
<ClaimType Id="applicationId">
  <DisplayName>Application Identifier</DisplayName>
  <DataType>string</DataType>
</ClaimType>
```

2. Add the **applicationId** claim as an input claim, defaulted from [the `OIDC:ClientId` claims resolver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview#openid-connect), to the **AzureInsights-Common** technical profile.

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="AzureInsights-Common">
  <InputClaims>
    ...
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="applicationId" PartnerClaimType="{property:ApplicationId}" DefaultValue="{OIDC:ClientId}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
  </InputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```